# python - xml/html parsing problam

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

I need to parse a given file into list of strings,
the given file style is this:

```
<DOC>
<DOCNUM> NUMBER </DOCNUM>
<DOCTYPE> TYPE </DOCTYPE>
<HEADER>
&SOMETHING
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<HEADLINE>
SOME TEXT
</HEADLINE>
TEXT
TEXT 
TEXT 
<TEXT>
<P>
INPUT TEXT1
</P>
<P>
INPUT TEXT2
</P>
.
.
.
</TEXT>
</BODY>
</DOC>
```

I need to make a list of all the TEXTi instances inside the P tag appearances.
i tried doing this with lxml xml parser but because &something isn't acceptable in the xml format it didn't work...
i tried using html parser but i didn't figure out exactly how to make it work.

does anyone know of a good way for me to get the list i need?

Answer (score 2):

[beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) seems to have no problem parsing it.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> doc = BS('''<DOC>
<DOCNUM> NUMBER </DOCNUM>
<DOCTYPE> TYPE </DOCTYPE>
<HEADER>
&SOMETHING
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<HEADLINE>
SOME TEXT
</HEADLINE>
TEXT
TEXT 
TEXT 
<TEXT>
<P>

INPUT TEXT1
</P>
<P>
INPUT TEXT2
</P>
.
.
.
</TEXT>
</BODY>
</DOC>''')

>>> list(chain(*[list(p.stripped_strings) for p in doc.find_all('p')]))
[u'INPUT TEXT1', u'INPUT TEXT2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use module `re` which imports regex functions:

```
import re
strr="<DOC> <DOCNUM> NUMBER </DOCNUM> <DOCTYPE> TYPE </DOCTYPE> <HEADER> &SOMETHING </HEADER> <BODY> <HEADLINE> SOME TEXT </HEADLINE> TEXT TEXT  TEXT  <TEXT> <P> INPUT TEXT1 </P> <P> INPUT TEXT2 </P> . . . </TEXT> </BODY> </DOC>"

arr = re.findall(r'<P>.*?</P>', strr)
print arr
```

This will work if you don't have nested `<P>` tags (however, any other tags can be in `<P>` tags)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `recover=True` option to ignore `&` in the `<HEADER>`:

```py
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse(xmlish_file, parser=etree.XMLParser(recover=True))
print([p.text for p in doc.iter('P')])
# -> ['\nINPUT TEXT1\n', '\nINPUT TEXT2\n']
```

Or you could parse it as html. If you are interested in all text inside `<p>`; you could use `.text_content()` instead of `.text`:

```py
from lxml import html

doc = html.parse(xmlish_file)
print([p.text_content() for p in doc.iter('p')])
# -> ['\nINPUT TEXT1\n', '\nINPUT TEXT2\n']
```